# Windows 7 Freezes Due To NTFS Corruption After Boot Into Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntfs, freeze, multi-boot

I manually partitioned space for Ubuntu 10.10 and installed it on my Windows 7 laptop. It installed successfully, and Windows 7 booted successfully but then froze after a few minutes. I removed the Ubuntu partition and re-installed using the Ubuntu installer partitioning and I got the same problem.

If I look at the partitions in gparted it says the ntfs file system is inconsistent and to run chkdsk /f. I can boot into safe mode in windows and do this, it does fix the freezing. My problem is that every time I boot into Ubuntu, the problem is created again.

I am looking for some pointers on how to investigate what is causing the NTFS corruption in the first place. I am guessing I need to take a closer look at the Grub2 configurations?

On a side note, the Grub menu also has a "Windows Vista" option which takes me to some weird windows screen then restarts (and also corrupts ntfs). I've seen this on other machines where Ubuntu was installed after Windows 7 and I'm curious what causes this.

Comment: Do you happen to have service pack 1 for Wind(bl)ows 7 installed?

Comment: Yes Windows 7 is as up to date as possible.

Comment: That's possibly the problem ;)

Comment: Your side note should be a separate question.